# find a file from a folder with a lot of sub-folders

Tags: linux, files, filesystems, command

There is a file named as `xyz.json` in a folder with a lot of files organized into multiple sub-folders. How to find this file?

Answer (score 2):

`find /path/to/folder -name xyz.json`

Answer (score 2):

```
$ find /path/to/top/dir -type f -name "xyz.json" -print
```

This will print the full path of all regular files called `xyz.json` in the directory structure rooted at `/path/to/top/dir`.

If you have a `locate` database that is updated with high enough frequency, you may also try

```
$ locate "/path/to/top/dir/*/xyz.json"
```